# How to use the curated zone in Azure Data Lake Storage in relation to Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse

I'm storing data in ADLS zones (Raw > Staging > Curated) which will be fed to a data warehouse. Think for example of Customer data from a CRM application:

Raw\CRM\Customer\2022\03\05\raw_crm_customer_2022_03_05.csv containing entries

1, John Smith,100

2, Mario Castillo,200

Raw\CRM\Customer\2022\03\06\raw_crm_customer_2022_03_06.csv containing entries:

2, Mario Castillo,300 //record has been modified

3, Mary Tyler, 500 // new record on 3rd March

So what should I store in the curated zone? What is the best naming convention?

Do I show an aggregation showing the latest modified version of each record? Or do I show historical records as well? For example, using aggregation on the last modified record:

1 John Smith, 100

2 Mario Castillo, 300

3 Mary Tyler,500

And what is the naming convention? Is it curated\CRM\Customer ?

My plan is to load historical data in the data warehouse from the curated zone.